# Rust Dockerfile for ARM64, built on intel hosts

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, arm, amazon-ecs

I am building Docker images for ARM64 chipset (AWS ECS `t4g` instances).
I run the Docker build on X86 host machines (Github actions runner and/or Intel mac).

This is my Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM rust:latest as builder

RUN mkdir /opt/myapp
WORKDIR /opt/myapp

ADD src/app/myapp/Cargo.toml src/app/myapp/Cargo.lock ./src/app/myapp/

WORKDIR /opt/myapp/src/app/myapp

# Add source code
ADD src/app/myapp/src src/

# Create binary (installed to system path)
# To prevent OOM error, try: cargo --config net.git-fetch-with-cli=true install --path .
RUN cargo install --path .

# Create image for ARM chipset instead of AMD
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 arm64v8/rust:1.70-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y qemu-user-static

# Copy the binary into this image
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp

CMD ["myapp"]
```

- Running this image in AWS ECS: `exec /usr/local/bin/myapp: exec format error` (implies incorrect chipset?)
- Running this image on Intel Mac: `WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64/v2) and no specific platform was requested exec /usr/local/bin/myapp: no such file or directory` (implies it *was* built for AMD...)

This is my Github Actions script:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU  # Required for ARM builds
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx  # Required for ARM builds
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: ${{ env.AWS_CICD_ROLE }}
          role-session-name: github-actions-session-${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build and push docker  # Required for ARM builds
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.ECR_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.ECR_REPOSITORY }}:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
          file: src/app/${{ env.ECS_SERVICE }}/Dockerfile
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha
          provenance: false
```

**I've also tried**

1. A single stage Dockerfile `FROM --platform=linux/arm64 arm64v8/rust:1.70` which works but takes 40+ minutes to build (presumably because my intel host is emulating ARM64 during the build?). This is unacceptably slow
2. `RUN cargo build --release --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` but get OpenSSL errors even after `apt-get install libssl-dev binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu`
3. `RUN cross build --release --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` but no luck

**Update:**
I got the ECS deployment working by updating the `platform` of `docker/build-push-action@v4` github action step to be `linux/arm64`. However this means the build step now takes 50+ minutes to build, which is unacceptable. I'm still looking for a way to build on X86 quickly (5 mins) for ARM64 target.

Comment: I've built ARM64 images on local Intel machines, and then deployed to ARM ECS, by using the Docker buildx multi-platform build support: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/ Unfortunately I have no idea how to make that work in GitHub Actions, so I'm not going to post an answer, but I would start by seeing if you can build that locally and if the time it takes is acceptable.

Comment: Actually it looks like what I posted regarding buildx multiplatform builds is exactly what your GitHub Actions step is doing. I'm guessing it takes so long because it's really building on an Intel machine and emulating ARM64 to do the build. If that's the case, then you will have to look into doing the actual build on an ARM machine instead of an Intel machine. I suggest looking into AWS CodeBuild for that, and just having GitHub Actions trigger the CodeBuild step.

Comment: @MarkB thanks, I've come to the same conclusion so far - even tempted to switch all our EC2 instances to AMD chipsets to reduce the headache! I'll take a look at AWS CodeBuild. This seems like a common use case though - I'm very surprised there aren't a plethora of examples for cargo builds in Docker targeting ARM64 from GH Actions, Mac Intel, etc

Comment: You have two options, emulate ARM on your Intel machine to do the build, which can be super slow as you have seen, or use an ARM build machine. Not sure there needs to be a plethora of examples for that, or why there would need to be cargo specific examples.

Comment: @MarkB I've cross-built docker machines on github actions before (without emulation): https://github.com/Finomnis/librespot-docker in case this helps anyone. I'm too lazy to write a full answer right now, so if someone wants to take the findings from my repository and write an answer out of them, feel free

Comment: There's some magic with buildx involved to switch back and forth between native and emulated docker in one script, and a little bit of environment magic variables to make the `cargo build` on x86 arm compatible.

Comment: Here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Finomnis/librespot-docker/blob/47cdab10f07d312e838c74e6bad3bdd3d6bf858c/docker/Dockerfile), and here's the [github actions script](https://github.com/Finomnis/librespot-docker/blob/47cdab10f07d312e838c74e6bad3bdd3d6bf858c/.github/workflows/docker-build.yml).

Comment: Also, you need to enable cross libraries in `apt-get` and then install the libraries your project depends on for the target platform (like `apt-get install libssl-dev:arm64`)